# regex to replace strings with img - js

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

hey there I am currently having the issues that I want to detect strings in a text with an image.

```
{"a":"img1.jpg", "ab":"img2.jpg"}
```

my current regex is:

```
/(a|ab)/g
```

When I have a text like:

```
yeah abc
```

it replaces the **"a" in the yeah with img1.jpg** but it also replaces the "ab"c with "img1.jpg".

I can avoid it through switching `/(ab|a)/` but this is can't be the solution, since I have a huge unsorted json list as expressions (a, ab is just for simplicity). The reason I am doing this is to replace native emojis with images.

**How can I say, that it only replaces the a if there is no b following?**

Comment: Just sort the list first, so that the longer alternatives come first

Comment: Or, if there are no whitespaces in the strings and they are all alphanumeric, and you want to match them as whole words, use `/\b(a|ab)\b/`

Comment: what if I have more than just a,ab? like ```/(a|ab|ac|b|bc|)/```. I somehow need to provide the uniqueness of it @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `/\b(a|ab|ac|b|bc)\b/` will be unique enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately it didn't work when I have actual emojis like:
```/\b(|‍❤️‍‍)\b/``` . they don't get recognized in the text ...

Comment: They won't be recognized since emojis are not letters. I would have never suggested word boundaries if you had revealed you are working with emojis.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the emoji keys in descendig order, then build your regex pattern like this:

```js
function replaceEmojis (str) {
  const emojis = {
    a: { src: 'imgA.jpg', color: 'red' },
    abc: { src: 'imgABC.jpg', color: 'green' },
    ab: { src: 'imgAB.jpg', color: 'blue' },
    bc: { src: 'imgBC.jpg', color: 'orange' }
  };
  
  const fnDescendingOrder = ([x, y]) => x > y ? -1 : +(x != y);

  const keys = Object.keys(emojis).sort((x, y) =>
    fnDescendingOrder(x.length == y.length ? [x, y] : [x.length, y.length])
  );

  const pattern = new RegExp(keys.join('|'), 'g');

  const transformed = str.replace(pattern, m => {
    const emoji = emojis[m];
    return '<img class="' + emoji.color + '" src="' + emoji.src + '">';
  });

  return transformed;
};

let str = 'yeah abc ab a abca bcaba';
result.innerHTML = replaceEmojis(str);
```

```css
img { width: 10px; height: 100%; }
img.red { background: red; }
img.green { background: green; }
img.blue { background: blue; }
img.orange { background: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

You have to sort in descending order first by length, next by alphabetical order. Cause `bc` should be checked after `abc`.

Comment: I am trying to sort it descending by the attribute instead of the the key, because I have an attribute for it. How can I sort an object of objects based on the objects property? Like sorting descending by property age:

    ```const arr = {
      a: { name: "Robin Van Persie", age: 28 },
      b: { name: "Theo Walcott", age: 22 },
      c: { name: "Bacary Sagna", age: 26 }
    }.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
      return obj2.age - obj1.age;
    });```

Comment: @André. The `sort` function is from `Array.prototype`, you need to be on an array instance to call it. Do it like: `arr = Object.values(obj);`, then `arr.sort((x, y) => x.age - y.age)`;